# Development on sony xperia neo v

Tags: android

I started android development.I have always made ​​use of emulators and eclipse. Because I'm doing more and more developing, I consider a device to buy.

I already have tested applications on the HTC Desire and google nexus s.

I want to buy a `sony ericson xperio neo v`, but do not know if this is the same?

`Problem: Is development for all devices with android the same?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes android os platform defines the development of the apps.  android
>   os for older version(up 2.3.7) is alright but if you switch to a tab
>   or platform 3.0 or higher it depends on device because screen size,
>   compatibility,processor etc.